# How should I properly use a friend declaration in a nested class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, friend

For example, suppose I made a code like :

```
class A
{
private:
    class B
    {
    private:
        int a;
        friend int A::foo(B &b);
    };
    int foo(B &b)
    {
        return b.a;
    }
};
```

Since `a` in `B` is private, to use `a` in function `foo` of `A`, I would use a `friend` so that `foo` can actually access `a`.

However this code gives error that it cannot access `a`. What is the problem of the code, and how should I change the code while keeping `a` private and `A` not being friend of `B`? Or is there a better way?

Comment: "and A not being friend of B" you mean B not being friend of A? I'm pretty sure it's not possible since you need the complete definition of either A or B beforehand.

Comment: `a` is private inside `class B`. To access a private member of a class, you may need a public method in `class B`, for example, `int get_a() { return a; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get only the `a` of `B` class you need a getter function. This should be the simplest way to go.

```
class B
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    // provide getter function
    const int& getMember_a()const { return a; }
};
```

and in the `foo` function

```
const int& foo(const B &b)const 
{
    return b.getMember_a(); // call the getter to get the a
}
```

---

Regarding the issue of your code; at the line `friend int A::foo(B &b);` in `B` class, it does not know that the function `A::foo`. Therefore we need to forward declare `int foo(B &);` before the class `B`. Then the question; whether `A::foo(B &)` knows about `B`. Also no. But fortunately, C++ allows having an incomplete type by forward declaring the classes as well. That means, following way-way, you can achieve the goal you want.

```
class A
{
private:
    class B;      // forward declare class B for A::foo(B &)
    int foo(B &); // forward declare the member function of A
    class B
    {
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        friend int A::foo(B &b);
    };
};
// define, as a non-member friend function
int A::foo(B &b)
{
    return b.a;
}
```